arXiv natbib warning but the references still work
I'm submitting some work to arXiv. I've included the .bbl file and given it the same name as the .tex file. However, when I process it I get loads of natbib errors:
Package natbib Warning: Citation `Simon2022' on page 1 undefined on input line 1
2.

The strange thing is that the pdf looks absolutely fine - all the references are there and are clickable. The warning still concerns me though. Can I safely ignore it?

Welcome! Maybe it is just a warning during the first run? Without showing a complete but minimal example, it is difficult to know. But if it looks OK in the end, I guess all is fine.

You wrote, "I get loads of natbib errors". However, you then you report warning messages, not error messages. It sounds like a first-stage run issue that was resolved during a later build stage. As @mickep has already noted in a coment, though, it's not possible to provide a definitive diagnosis of what's going on solely on the basis of the rather limited information you've provided so far.
